# Async API method using AsyncRequestHandler too many threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, async-await, mediatr

I guess my question boils down to:

> Given two async methods where one calls the other. Should I await in both of the methods, or just the first?

Here's my scenario.
I'm writing an ASP NET CORE WEB API using CQRS and MediatR.

I have this async API method

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Get.Query query)
{
    var result = await _mediator.Send(query);
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Should I also async/await in my `RequestHandler`?
Like this

```
public class QueryHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler<Query, IEnumerable<Result>>
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Handle(Query message)
    {
        return await _connection.QueryAsync<Result>("...");
    }
}
```

Or should I simply do this

```
public class QueryHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler<Query, IEnumerable<Result>>
{
    public Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Handle(Query message)
    {
        return _connection.QueryAsync<Result>("...");
    }
}
```

The reason I'm puzzled is because the API request is already in a thread. So is wrapping it in another thread not the correct way to do it? I've seen examples of both :/

Comment: Async/await does not cause things to get wrapped in threads. Only doing a explicit `Task.Run(` causes it to be wrapped in a thread.

Comment: Hmm seems I need to read up on async/await

Comment: I believe awaiting and returning the task itself ultimately don't matter as the thread handling the request will ultimately be released during io operations. But i like to go with the second option because i believe it requires less context switching between threads